# Why getting nil in collectionView image from json in swift

Tags: json, swift, uicollectionview, uiimageview, imageurl

I have collectionview with image and label... I'm able to display text values from json to label and I'm getting all img urls from json to `cellForItemAtindexPath` but all those images i am unable to show in collectionview.. i have all 20 image urls in `cellForItemAtindexPath` i can see it in console but why i am unable to display them in collectionview.

here is my code:

```
 import UIKit
 import SDWebImage
 struct JsonData {

var iconHome: String?
var typeName: String?
var id: String?
init(icon: String, tpe: String, id: String) {
    self.iconHome = icon
    self.typeName = tpe
    self.id = id
}
}

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate, URLSessionDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
var itemsArray = [JsonData]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    homeServiceCall()
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return itemsArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionViewCell

    let aData = itemsArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.paymentLabel.text = aData.typeName
    cell.paymentImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:aData.iconHome!)) { (_, error, _, _) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    print("tableview collection images \(String(describing: aData.iconHome))")
   return cell
}
//MARK:- Service-call

func homeServiceCall(){

    let urlStr = "https://********/webservices//getfinancer"
    let url = URL(string: urlStr)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

        guard let respData = data else {
            return
        }
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }
        do{
            let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: respData, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]
            let financerArray = jsonObj["financer"] as! [[String: Any]]

             for financer in financerArray {
             guard let id = financer["id"] as? String else { break }
             guard let pic = financer["icon"] as? String else { break }
             guard let typeName = financer["tpe"] as? String else { break }
             print("the json icons \(String(describing: pic))")

             let jsonDataObj = JsonData(icon: pic, tpe: typeName, id: id)
             self.itemsArray.append(jsonDataObj)
             }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("catch error")
        }
    }).resume()
}
}
```

when i print image urls in `cellForItemAtindexPath` i got all 20 image urls in console.. but why i am unable to show them in collectionview.

i am getting output like below.. some images are showing and some are not if i give placeholder image in `sd_setImage` then it shoes placeholder image in collectionview why??

here is my output:

[image]

some images are coming and some are not but there are no nil images in server all images are coming in json.. i got stuck here from long time.. anyone please help me here.

Comment: Use the `sd_setImage()` which has the completion closure where you can output error if there is one. Also, what's the size of your images? Because if they are heavy, slow network, etc.

Comment: @Larme i have updated my post `sd_setImage() ` with clouser them i am getting  Error Domain=SDWebImageErrorDomain Code=-1 "Trying to load a nil url" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Trying to load a nil url}

Comment: @Larme but i am getting all image urls in `cellForItemAtindexPath ` i can print in console

Comment: When you have error, print `aData.iconHome` & `URL(string: aData.iconHome)`? Might need percent escapes.

Comment: @Larme what should i do then?

Comment: Is that the case? Is URL(string: aData.iconHome!) nil? Could you show an example of them? If you copy/paste it in Safari, does it succeed? If yes, is it identical or does it have percent signs now? If yes look for percent escape url swift

Comment: @Larme i have one nil image from json so how can I check that nil and display all working img urls in collectionview.. please tell me

Comment: `if let error = error { print("Error: \(error)"); print("aData.iconHome: \(aData.iconHome)"); print("url: \(URL(string:aData.iconHome ?? ""))"}`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/JxwFBBKf Please give the output. We can't guess what's wrong exactly if you don't want to debug.

Comment: I just checked, why duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58292027/how-to-add-json-images-in-collectionview-without-nil-in-swift ?

Comment: @Larme i don't know how to use pastebin.com/JxwFBBKf so can i share my only the above code in gitgub link so You can understand where i did mistake in code.. i got stuck here from long time

Comment: Copy/paste the code of the pastebin, just before you do `self.collectionView.reloadData()`. Or after `guard let respData = data else { return }`, do `print("JSON: \(String(data: respData, encoding: .utf8)")`

Comment: @Larme as u mentioned i did like this if let error = error { print("Error: \(error)"); print("aData.iconHome: \(aData.iconHome)"); print("url: \(URL(string:aData.iconHome ?? ""))"} .      then output https://pastebin.com/WnAe6p7B

Comment: `"https://anyemi.com/PaySTAR//images/varun finance5_icon.png"`. Copy paste this one into your web browser. You'll see that it will change the URL to "%20". Look for "Percent Escape URL Swift".

Comment: @Larme one last doubt.. remaining are coming then why they are not displaying... and can u pls tell me how to use Percent Escape URL Swift.. first time i am facing this kind of issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using Swift so i recommend that you should use [KingFisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) instead of SDWebImage to handle images from urls.

I checked your code, everything is fine. However, when you load image from url, some of them throw this error:

`A URL session error happened. The underlying error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 \"The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “anyemi.com” which could put your confidential information at risk."`

This error happens for urls with domain `anyemi.com`.
For example:
https://anyemi.com/PaySTAR/images/LSPUBLICSCHOOL_icon.png
https://anyemi.com/PaySTAR/images/CDMA_icon.png

Urls with domain `dev.anyemi.com` work well. For example:
https://dev.anyemi.com/maheshbank/icons/electricity.png
https://dev.anyemi.com/maheshbank/icons/gas.png

Therefore the problem is in SSL configuration of your backend. For now, you can change the url with domain `anyemi.com` to `dev.anyemi.com` for testing and i believe that it will work well.

Comment: hi why everyone suggesting me kingfisher, what is the problem with SDWebImage

Comment: Maybe, let's try because it's support well for Swift while SDWebImage is written in Objective C for long time

Comment: Ii have installed kingfisher still getting nil.. but images are coming from json.. maybe i did mistake in nil handling

Comment: can i share my homeVC code through github link so you can find the mistake in code.. then i will check with my backend team about the images.. tell me pls i got stuck here from long time

Comment: Thank you so much.. github link https://github.com/SwiftSamples/HomeBug    pls go through my code

Comment: I checked your code and updated my answer, please check @iosSwift

Comment: thank you so much!! upvoted and accepted.. one last doubt is there any way from my side to show `anyemi.com ` domain images in screen or only backend team need to change.

Comment: can i change anyemi.com to dev.anyemi.com for testing

Comment: You should ask your backend team to see what happen to with the urls with `anyemi.com` domain. @iosSwift.

Comment: You also should use a placeholder to display in case that the image is not loaded. 
`if let url = URL(string: aData.iconHome!) {
            cell.paymentImage.kf.setImage(with: url, placeholder: yourPlaceHolderImage, options: nil, progressBlock: nil) { (result) in
                switch result {
                case .success(_):
                       // Image loaded
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Error \(error.errorDescription)")
                }
            }
        }`
Let pass a placeholder (an instance of UIImage) to this function

Comment: please try to anser this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58345607/how-to-send-otp-to-registered-mobile-number-in-swift

Comment: Just give an answer for that question @iosSwift. Good luck.