# How to send OTP to registered mobile number in swift?

Tags: json, swift, iphone, sendmessage, one-time-password

In my app while register i need to send otp to registered number but i am unable to send otp to register number. for registration i have two apis one is register and otpverify... when I click registerButton then i need to send otp to registered mobile num...here how to sen otp to registered mobile number?

Here is my total code:

```
import UIKit
class RegistrationViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{

//MARK:- Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var phoneNumTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var conformPasswordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var otpTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var registerButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var sendOtpButton: UIButton!

var otpField: Int?

//MARK:- lifecycle methods

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.phoneNumTextField.keyboardType = .phonePad

    otpTextField.isHidden = true
}
//MARK:- ButtonActions

@IBAction func registerButton(_ sender: Any) {
            registerService()
}

@IBAction func sendOTPButton(_ sender: Any) {

    otpService()
}

//MARK:- Service part
func registerService(){

    print("register tapped")

    let parameters = ["mobile_number": Int(phoneNumTextField.text ?? "") as Any,
                      "email":emailTextField.text as Any,
                      "password":passwordTextField.text as Any,
                      "name": nameTextField.text as Any]

    let url = URL(string: "https://webservices/register")
    var req =  URLRequest(url: url!)
    req.httpMethod = "POST"
    req.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Contet-Type")
    req.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted) else {return}
    req.httpBody = httpBody
    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: req, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if response != nil {
            // print(response)
        }
        if let data = data {

            do{
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: Any]
                let phNum = json["mobile_number"] as? Int
                self.otpField = json["otp"] as? Int
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.otpTextField.text = self.otpField as? String
                }
            }catch{
                print("error")
            }
        }
    }).resume()
}

func otpService(){

    let parameters = ["mobile_number": phoneNumTextField.text as Any,
                      "otp": otpTextField.text as Any]

    let url = URL(string: "https://webservices//otpverify")
    var req =  URLRequest(url: url!)
    req.httpMethod = "POST"
    req.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Contet-Type")
    req.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted) else {return}
    req.httpBody = httpBody
    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: req, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if response != nil {
            // print(response)
        }
        if let data = data {

            do{
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: Any]
                let mobileNum = json["mobile_number"] as! [String : Any]

                let Uid = mobileNum["id"] as? String
                let name = mobileNum["name"] as? String
                let phNum = mobileNum["username"] as? String

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if (self.otpTextField.text == String(self.otpField!)){
                        print("registration successfullllll...")

                        let loginVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
                        self.present(loginVC, animated: true)
                    }
                    else{
                        print("register fail")
                    }
                }
            }catch{
                print("error")
            }
        }
    }).resume()
}
}
```

Here how to send otp to registerd mobile number. please help me here.

Comment: Please help me here.

Comment: Although you can use a third party service on client but it's not what you do on client side. Ask your backend to handle this. Once you make a register call, your backend should use any third party service to send message on mobile number. You should only ask the user to input the OTP received and then call the verification api for its correctness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one thing you should notice:

- You repeated your code: Calling web service. You should have a class in charge of this, you just pass the method (post, get ...) and the parameters.

Regarding to sending OTP to registered phone number, it should be the responsibility of your backend.

And also, it's not the value of otpTextField like this code

`let parameters = ["mobile_number": phoneNumTextField.text as Any,
                   "otp": otpTextField.text as Any]`

There're some third parties who can help on phone verification (include sending otp of course) like AccountKit of Facebook (but unfortunately, it stopped since Sep 2019) or Twilio (seems like the best choice at this time).

You can follow this to integrate Twilio phone verification into your application:  https://www.twilio.com/blog/phone-verification-in-ios-with-twilio-verify-and-swift-html

Comment: thanks for the answer..if i run app in simulator then i am getting otp in console. but when i test app in device i am not getting otp in registered number? why? please once go through my above code. am i did any mistake in code

Comment: Your above lines of code or the sample code of Twilio @iosSwift?

Comment: my above posted code.. bcz my backend says they have intigrated for sending otp to phone num.. when i hit registerButton then i need to send otp to num

Comment: Provide me the endpoint then i can check the log and see what's going wrong

Comment: Sorry @iosSwift, i have no experience with that issue, will help you next times

Comment: tnx for the reply, i have delated that message

Comment: if u spend some time for answer i will share code using github for your better understand... if u don't have time its okay no problem

Comment: Okay share me github link, i will take a look @iosSwift

Comment: in code if u click any item in home should compare typeName with nextVC categoryName and display values in table view..... for trail if u click last item in HomeVC and in my AllMakePaymentVC if u uncommennt if "DTH" condition then u can understand how it works

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is purely backend's responsibility to do but if you still want to try you need to look for some third party api , like twillio sms/otp services and that too if they provide http REST services APIs so that you can hit api from front end directly.